# How to stop implicit response header in express.js and as well as in node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to response a request with my own custom response header. node's

```
res.writeHead()
```

method lets me do so. But I'm using express and when I explicitly don't write the

```
X-powered-by : x-foo
```

Express uses

```
X-powered-by : Express
```

So how do I stop this implicit response header being sent to the browser?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For Express, it's an [application setting](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.settings.table) that you can disable:

```
app.set('x-powered-by', false);
```